# How to blur CSS ::selection backgorund

Tags: css

I'm trying to blur the background color of my CSS `::selection` (the blue background color that appears when you select text)

I tried `backdrop-filter` which didn't work and now wonder if it's even possiblem. I hope I can get some help!

Comment: [MDN suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection#allowable_properties) there are a very limited set of supported properties for `::selection` (And bare in mind, this is a feature that some people may rely on for accessibility reasons and over-stylising it is generally not a good idea)

Comment: Oh, there are only the `color` and `background-color` properties? @DBS

Comment: Effectively, yes. Just a few text formatting rules and `background-color`

Comment: Alright, that's fine with me. Was just wondering if it was possible. Thanks!